# Sync Database from one to the other Sever with a SQL/Batch Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need a generalized script which syncs one DB from one server to another or the same server.

Server: MSSQL 2014 SP1

My first thought was to cycle through a database and copy every table like this:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE');
DECLARE @null INT = 1;

WHILE @null <= @cnt
BEGIN
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE';
    SET @null = @null +1;
END;
```

But with this method i will miss some important data and it will copy all the data and not only the missing ones, which would result in some heavy load on the network and servers because our DBs are up to 500GB large.

Any idea?

Comment: Is this a one-off task, or on-going?  If the latter, do the two dbs need to remind in sync, or is a periodic update enough?

Comment: Its a periodic update. I will run the script when i need it.

Comment: This is not [tag:batch-file]-related! Please read the tag info before applying tags next time. Thank you!

Comment: It is. you could do a batch-file/sql-script combination. I asked for a script NOT a SQL-Script. It could have been a PHP/SQL script too. Think before commenting!

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods you could use.

**Method 001: SSMS Copy Db Wizard**
From SQL Server Management Studio; right click on the source database.  Choose *Tasks* >> *Copy Database...*.  This will launch the [copy database wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard).  Within the wizard you can choose which objects are/are not copied.

**Method 002: SSIS**
Use [SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services) to create a pacakge that contains a [Transfer Database Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/transfer-database-task).

SSIS packages can be scheduled with the SQL Agent, if you want to repeat the task on a fixed schedule.

You can also execute the package via a script, for ad-hoc updates.